# View all spam for domain in mailcleaner

Tags: spam

I have the community edition of MailCleaner. Is it possible to view all messages that were marked as spam from the admin website or cli?

I see the `/admin/managespamquarantine` and `/admin/managecontentquarantine` pages, but that assumes you know the user's information.

Answer (score 0):

On `/admin/managespamquarantine` and `/admin/managecontentquarantine` put an `@` in the `Address Displayed` box then select the domain and press refresh. This will display all messages to that domain.